# Stop loss in Pine?

Tags: pine-script

I would like to set a stop loss on each of my entries. The stop loss would triger if the price goes down by 2% from the entry price

```
//@version=5
strategy(title="Test ", calc_on_every_tick=false)

haHandle=ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
haOpen=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,open)
haClose=request.security(haHandle,timeframe.period,close)
haDeltaAbs=haClose-haClose[1]
haDeltaRel=haDeltaAbs/haClose[1]*100
haEntryCondition = haDeltaRel > 0 and haDeltaRel[1] < 0
strategy.entry("trade", strategy.long, when = haEntryCondition, stop = ????)
strategy.close("trade", when = ta.falling(haClose, 1))    
plot(na, "Zero line", color.gray)
```

But there is no indications in Pine documentation on how to use this "stop" argument, is it at least the right argument for setting a stop-loss ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `strategy.exit()` for that.

```
sl_per = input.float(2.0) * 0.01
sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_per)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("SL", "trade", stop=sl_price)
```